# How can I speedup this Julia code?

Tags: performance, julia, number-theory

The code implements an example of a Pollard rho() function for finding a factor of a positive integer, n. I've examined some of the code in the Julia "Primes" package that runs rapidly in an attempt to speedup the pollard_rho() function, all to no avail. The code should execute n = 1524157897241274137 in approximately 100 mSec to 30 Sec (Erlang, Haskell, Mercury, SWI Prolog) but takes about 3 to 4 minutes on JuliaBox, IJulia, and the Julia REPL. How can I make this go fast?

pollard_rho(1524157897241274137) = 1234567891

```
__precompile__()
module Pollard

export pollard_rho

function pollard_rho{T<:Integer}(n::T)
    f(x::T, r::T, n) = rem(((x ^ T(2)) + r), n)
    r::T = 7; x::T = 2; y::T = 11; y1::T = 11; z::T = 1
    while z == 1
        x  = f(x, r, n)
        y1 = f(y, r, n)
        y  = f(y1, r, n)
        z  = gcd(n, abs(x - y))
    end
    z >= n ? "error" : z
end

end # module
```

Comment: You can call `x  = f(x, r, n)` and `y1 = f(y, r, n)` on different threads. Also, is there a reason why `r` and `x` aren't of type `T`?

Comment: Thank you. I declared the type of r and x when I defined f, and had received cautions when I repeated the typing in the local variables. At least, that was my understanding of what the cautions were reporting.

Comment: It looks like it's all typed well. The problem when profiling is all due to the `gcd` function: it's taking about 85% of the time for me. Maybe Julia's `gcd` in Base needs some work. Do you know what algorithms the other languages use? Here's Julia's: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/intfuncs.jl#L3

Comment: Yes, I wrote the ones I use in the other languages. They are tail-recursive versions of the imperative code used here. Julia's "factor()" runs that value of n in just over one second. My code, above, runs it in about 200 seconds. Something is badly amiss, but don't know what it is. Thanks for the feedback that the code is well typed.

Comment: You might want to open an issue on Julia's Github. https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues

Answer (score 12):

There are quite a few problems with type instability here.

1. Don't return either the string `"error"` or a result; instead explicitly call `error()`.
2. As Chris mentioned, `x` and `r` ought to be annotated to be of type `T`, else they will be unstable.

There also seems to be a potential problem with overflow. A solution is to widen in the squaring step before truncating back to type `T`.

```
function pollard_rho{T<:Integer}(n::T)
    f(x::T, r::T, n) = rem(Base.widemul(x, x) + r, n) % T
    r::T = 7; x::T = 2; y::T = 11; y1::T = 11; z::T = 1
    while z == 1
        x  = f(x, r, n)
        y1 = f(y, r, n)
        y  = f(y1, r, n)
        z  = gcd(n, abs(x - y))
    end
    z >= n ? error() : z
end
```

After making these changes the function will run as fast as you could expect.

```
julia> @btime pollard_rho(1524157897241274137)
  4.128 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
1234567891
```

To find these problems with type instability, use the `@code_warntype` macro.

Comment: I thought the instability on the return wouldn't matter here since the return isn't used?

Comment: Yes, it wouldn't matter much if this is for end user use directly from the REPL. But it would be important if other higher-level functions call `pollard_rho`.

Comment: When I change in your code `Base.widemul(x,x)` back to `x*x` the computation time increases to 42 seconds. Looking at `@code_native` for the both of these individually they both reduce to an `imulq` operation. Why has `widemul` still such a big impact?

Comment: Without `widemul` you overflow `Int64` and the algorithm erroneously iterates 179216149 times.  The correct computation only iterates 16752 times.